# Where does Rage store its savegames?

Tags: rage

I can't find where RAGE is storing its savegames. It's not in AppData, and not in my documents, nor in the installation folder.

Does anyone know where the save games are saved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The save games should be located at: `"C:\Users\<username>\Saved Games\id Software\Rage\base\savegame\"`.